# WaitForSingleObject Deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, waitforsingleobject

Some background if you're interested, otherwise you can go right to the question at the bottom:

I am running into an issue where i have an infinite `while` loop with two `if` conditions checking for two event object states to become signaled.

```
while(1)
{
    if(DAQ_Comm_Server::usb_detect_flag == false)
    {
        if(WaitForSingleObject(USB_PHY_CONN,INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            DAQ_Comm_Server::usb_detect_flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(DAQ_Comm_Server::usb_detect_flag == true)
    {
        if(WaitForSingleObject(USB_PHY_DISCONN, INFINITE) == NULL)
        {
            DAQ_Comm_Server::usb_detect_flag = false;
        }   
    }
}
```

The event objects `USB_PHY_CONN` and `USB_PHY_DISCONN` are being set in my OS/BSP USB driver code where it will detect the hardware USB connection and proceed to use `SetEvent()` to set the corresponding event object.

Reading the documentation for `WaitForSingleObject()`, it does not explicitly state that it must be used inside a thread, although after reading it multiple times I feel like it is implied, but im not 100% sure.

The issue I am having is the first time the code runs through the while loop (i.e., usb is initially disconnected, then connected, and disconnected), my system runs fine and does not hang. However, Upon reconnecting the USB, my system freezes. My device becomes unresponsive/UI freezes and the code is lost.

Now, the moment i kill the process where I have the above code in, everything starts back up and continues to run fine. I did some reading and it seems that `WaitForSingleObject()` runs the risk of a possible deadlock, but I also noticed that it was always in terms of threads.

**My question is**, does `WaitForSingleObject()` HAVE to be used in a thread? If i use it in an infinite loop in a main, does this run a high risk of a deadlock/system freezing?

Note: This is a platform builder windows embedded CE 7 project with VS2008.

Comment: If you use `WaitForSingleObject` on a UI thread then message processing will stop and the system will potentially treat your window as non-responsive. Have a look at `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` instead.

Comment: And if you only have the thread from `main`, that must logically be your UI thread as well. (Windows allows you to use _any_ thread as a UI thread, doesn't need to be the `main` thread. If you like to live dangerously, you can even have one UI thread _per window_ !)

Comment: @MSalters My UI thread is in another process.

Comment: @Javia1492: I'm pretty sure your UI thread is _not_ in another process. Windows doesn't allow that. The UI thread of a window is by definition the thread which created the window. If it's **your** window (i.e. **your** process created and controls it) then its UI thread is a thread in your process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute code *outside* a thread! There's a "main" thread which starts at `main` but that too is a thread like any other.

That said, a deadlock requires 2 threads and 2 synchronization points. One thread locks A, another thread locks B, and then both threads block as they try to acquire the other lock.

This can be solved absolutely by having a lock order. If lock A is *always* locked before B, then no deadlock can occur between threads that have A and other threads that have lock B.

A more theoretical approach proves that the problem is a cycle in the lock graph. The cycle A<=>B is the simplest cycle of length 2. A->B->C->A can deadlock as well. A Directed Acyclic Graph of lock orders corresponds to a deadlock-free program.

Comment: And, as always, [Don't forget to include the message queue in your lock hierarchy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/18/10154966.aspx).

Comment: Ok, so i didnt realize that my main would function as a thread as well.

Comment: @Javia1492: The primary thread doesn't *"function"* as a thread. It **is** a [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)). You cannot ever run code outside of a thread.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you for the explanation. That answered my question and also helped me narrow down my specific issue.